# change the style of the number in stock to be 0 in red

Tags: vue.js

How can I change the style of the number in stock when 0, 0 needs to be in red?
So basically I have a displayed number in stock that increments and decrements if you add an item to a cart. But if number in stock is 0, I need 0  to be red color. How can I do it?

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
            <div class="cart">
                <p>Cart({{ cart }})</p>
            </div>
            <product @add-to-cart="updateCart" @remove-from-cart="removeItem"></product>
            </div>
```

VUE.js:

```
Vue.component('product', {

    template: 
    `
     <div class="product">
          
        <div class="product-image">
          <img :src="image" />
        </div>
  
        <div class="product-info">
            <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
            <p v-if=  "inStock > 0"> In Stock: {{inStock}}</p>
            <p v-else>No more in stock {{inStock}}</p>
  
            <button @click="addToCart" 
              :disabled="!inStock"
              :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }"> + </button>

            <button @click="removeFromCart"
            :disabled="inStock==10"> - </button>
            
  
         </div>  
      
      </div>
     `,
    data() {
      return {
          product: 'Hoodie',
          image: 'hoodie.jpeg',
          inStock: 10,
          cart: 0
      }
    },
     methods: {
        addToCart: function() {
            this.$emit('add-to-cart'),
            this.inStock -= 1
        },
        removeFromCart: function() {
             this.$emit('remove-from-cart'),
             this.inStock += 1
        }
      }
  })

var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        cart: 0
      },
      methods: {
        updateCart() {
          this.cart  += 1
        },
        removeItem() {
          this.cart  -= 1
        }
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `class` on an element dynamically, using `:class` with an object.

For example:

```
<p:class="{ isRed: inStock === 0 }">{{ inStock }}</p>
```

This will apply the class `isRed` on this `p` if `inStock` is 0.

You then just need to define the appropriate `css` for `isRed`:

```
.isRed {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: where do I add this class to?

Comment: Add it to whichever element you want to be red when `inStock` is `0`, so in your above example, the `<p v-else>`